# Need to convert entire case statement to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Writing a SQL extract for NACHRI submission. SSMS v17.6

Need weight in ounces converted to grams (whole number only), with an additional clause to change NULL values to '----' (four dashes-no quotes). This four dashes bit is causing the whole thing to need to be VARCHAR but I am not sure how to do that with a numeric equation.

I am getting

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric

in the following case statement:

```
',CASE WHEN baby.OB_DEL_BIRTH_WT > 0 THEN CEILING(baby.OB_DEL_BIRTH_WT/0.035274)
        when baby.OB_DEL_BIRTH_WT is null then '----' end as weight_gm'
```

Examples of correct answers would look like this:

```
3534, 
'----',
2784,
3556,
'----'
----
----
```

Comment: `case` is an *expression* not a *statement* :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cast()`:

```
(CASE WHEN baby.OB_DEL_BIRTH_WT > 0
       THEN CAST(CEILING(baby.OB_DEL_BIRTH_WT/0.035274) as VARCHAR(255))
      WHEN baby.OB_DEL_BIRTH_WT IS NULL 
      THEN '----' 
 END) as weight_gm
```

Or, assuming that weights are always greater than `0` (reasonable), then just use `COALESCE()`:

```
COALESCE(CAST(CEILING(baby.OB_DEL_BIRTH_WT/0.035274) as VARCHAR(255)), '----')
```

Note that you still need the `CAST()`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you share table structures of baby.
Do you need the values as comma separated single field? Then use below query:

```
 SELECT distinct
        abc = STUFF(
                     (SELECT ',' + (CASE WHEN baby.OB_DEL_BIRTH_WT > 0
           THEN CAST(CEILING(baby.OB_DEL_BIRTH_WT/0.035274) as VARCHAR(255))
          WHEN baby.OB_DEL_BIRTH_WT IS NULL 
          THEN '''----''' 
     END) FROM baby FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
                   ) 
    FROM baby
```

This will return a single row like this  3534, '----',2784,3556,'----'